# Java powers of base 10 and exponents up to 15

Tags: java

I want to implement the powers of 10 from 10^1 to all the way to 10^15. I have been asked not to use the math class to implement this.

```
public class Powers {

public static void main(String[] args) {

for(int index = 1; index <=15; index++)
System.out.println("10 to the power of 1 is" + 10*index);


 }
 }
```

This is what i have got so far, any suggestions what I could do?

Comment: In java or python?

Comment: @TaohidulIslam Java sir.

Comment: You could write your own `pow` method, or take advantage of the fact that `10**n == 10**(n-1) * 10` and keep a running product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     long temp = 1;
     for(int index = 1; index <=15; index++) {
         System.out.println("10 to the power of " + index + " is " + 10 * temp);
         temp *= 10;
     }
 }
```

Hope, it will help.

Edit:

> When index is 1, then temp is 1, so output is 10 * 1 = 10 and temp = 1 *
>   10 = 10
>
> When index is 2, then temp is 10, so output is 10 * 10 = 100 and temp = 10
>   * 10 = 100
>
> When index is 3, then temp is 100, so output is 10 * 100 = 1000 and temp =
>   100 * 10 = 1000
>
> When index is 4, then temp is 1000, so output is 10 * 1000 = 10000 
>   and temp = 1000 * 10 = 10000

it goes on till index value is 15. Hope it is clear now.

Comment: this was really helpful but I am confused what is making the code do what is doing and I need some clarification

Comment: I understand the long data type allows big numbers to be stored and if it was integer it wouldnt allow 10^15 to be stored. But what I feel confused on is the where the println statement is made and also the temp*= 10;

Comment: This (corrected) answer beat my answer. The only beef I have with it, in its current version, is that it uses twice as many multiplications as necessary. Although I suspect most compilers will deal with this in compilation.

Comment: Really helpful I appreciate it. I get it now!!! So everytime temp gets multiplied by 10 in the for loop to give the specified output.

Comment: Yes, you are right @john. Best of luck.